# Google Form: map multiple answer to unique decimal numer

Tags: google-forms

I have a Google Form where user can select multiple answers from few questions. How to map the user's section to unique decimal number as output.
E.g.

```
Q1. Select your age group (User can select only one value here):
o 25-30
o 30-35
o 35-40
etc

Q2. What type of exercise do you do (User can select multiple choices here):
[] Walk
[] Run
[] HIIT 
etc
```

Assume Q1A represents Q1 Answer A (first answer), Q1C represents Q1 Answer C (last answer) etc.
A value 0 means it is not selected, a value 1 means it is selected by user.

I want to map each of the possible combination of user choices to one unique decimal number as output. It looks like below binary table.

```
Q1A Q1B Q1C Q2A Q2B Q2C    Output (Decimal mapping)
1    0   0  1   0   0       1
1    0   0  0   1   0       2
1    0   0  0   0   1       3
```

Is there a way to google form automatically give the output as a unique decimal digit based on user's selection? If if it gives binary number, there could be any function to convert binary number to decimal number.

Tried few google searches to find the answer but didn't get better answer.